# Elements appearing twice on Wordpress Homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I've designed a page on elementor. And, the elements are appearing twice. Where the footer should have begun, the hero & the rest of the area is beginning again.

Below is the website.

https://scrapix.in/

The area where it should have ended is "Servicing customers worldwide"